# Need help understanding php signature verification

Tags: php, openssl, digital-signature

I am trying to verify a signature in php, and have exhausted myself trying every example I have found on the net. I've gone round in circles so much I have probably missed the solution now.

So I have test data which is

```
$msg = "test data";
```

which produced this signature using the private key from my key pair

```
$signature = "avALtk00btVyV74e5UdXJ/VClVV/fsuoLZpXQjiCrkVijsmMZsYWZujN56+Aa2CEQYkomDsm9CJ/Tue7lNP0tYVZz9Y0RngpcV9VT9V3i+3rbvbBEnuJuS/5e+PR7kQGMh8rVuCtHpAJhSePMyipC3kM90EQJ0jyY3rFaHDNpSzVBpOnRYLzqbsdy45v0bN78A2J/HaIhJy87Sh4X1a+WMg9PLkqSSYZnRYOB8XVDCYfyeeekcvI4rvP51wBQcaLwu7S0xPQA8yHfJqMXCqdmBVUQZrk/X+CujdXUyJItDWA8j2N8AHmcAD5oRaJ6bX3zCQFM1QnKMi1ETLudzIqfA==";
```

and this is the public key from the signing key pair

```
$key = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAxv4nCiH4vXvSLsvlceCOk3yfH1EQgNqNaVGdnFxdw9IIjSVZvTVH45NCodCJ0GlHoDwQM7DMV1+QrtF91cn44xg4Ys9zr1xkaT4jWBTe3YKoTqJoLHR4UU03F6Y1jTELhjY2a2Kt0ijyvAOKM4bm3gCItfMx59ETGInz7Oubb1T4IJ8TuWmZsh+X57c6fgv0B2+eTr/5FMK2VxXV5tHkB9UNLBgnbw0IZuC6izF4OFk9hxgh96i5wCf2HhHaNoEryx7ZV2ZG9a0OQnYZ+x1zaOIw6dJkV7rip3H57ksQfoQWM0GKMBB7cWIgWsf/GlbYTVgw26MvzEzGPb9uCfx8rwIDAQAB";
```

I have tried wrapping the key with this

```
$pubkey = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----" . $key . "-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

and with this

```
$pubkey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" . $key . "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

I have tried creating a public key id with both wrappings and without any wrapping, like this

```
$pubkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_public($pubkey);
$pubkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_public($key);
```

and I have tried verifying the signature with $key and $pubkeyid, with various algorithms and with none, like this

```
openssl_verify($msg, base64_decode($signature), $pubkeyid);
openssl_verify($msg, base64_decode($signature), $key);
openssl_verify($msg, base64_decode($signature), $pubkeyid, "sha256withRSAEncryption");
openssl_verify($msg, base64_decode($signature), $key, "sha256withRSAEncryption");
openssl_verify($msg, base64_decode($signature), $pubkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
openssl_verify($msg, base64_decode($signature), $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
```

I probably tried some other permutations, but can't remember now. My head hurts.

No matter what I tried, I have not managed to verify the signature. I can verify the signature using the public key in java easily.

I loathe asking for a working php example because I have tried so many I have already found on the net and just can't get them to work. Unfortunately phpseclib is not an option for me, so I have to use openssl.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How did you generate the signature? Have you confirmed that `openssl_pkey_get_public` isn't returning false before trying to use it? What is the source of the key used for signing? What format is it in?

Comment: Have you thought of using a libary, there a a few good ones out there that may help you, LibSodium, HaLite or PHPSecLib just to name a few.  In general they use OpenSSL if it's available (and fall back to a pure PHP implementation if its not),  But the real benefit is a OOP interface and more logical workflow for your code.  `Unfortunately phpseclib is not an option for me`  Why not, if I may ask?

Comment: @miken32 good point, I haven't checked the return value from openssl_pkey_get_public for a while now. Just checked and it returns false from both wrappings and if I just use key without a wrapping. The signature was generated in java and verified in java, before sending it to the php script. The signature and public key received in the php script have been checked against their values in the java program to make sure they are the same.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I can't use phpseclib because the anal web host refuses to load it. I decided to try using openssl instead of trying to load phpseclib locally, but have been swallowed up in this nightmare, so not got round to it. I think I'm at the stage I need to do that so I can use RSA, but I'll look in to those libraries you mentioned, if I can load them locally.

Comment: Confirmed your key looks good, but it needs to be in X.509 format with `PUBLIC KEY` header and footer on separate lines (not `RSA PUBLIC KEY`).

Comment: @miken32 I added line breaks to put the PUBLIC KEY tags on separate lines but it still did not verify the signature. I'll give it another go tomorrow, it's late and I'm beat. Thanks for confirming the key for me. So if I have this rightin my head, I need to add a line break between the start PUBLIC KEY tag and the key, and also between the key and the end PUBLIC KEY tag. Then pass it in to openssl_pkey_get_public, and use the resultant public key id in the verify function? Also, what algo do I specify on in the verify function 4th parameter?

Comment: Given the value you have for `$key` above, you want `$key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n$key\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";` Algorithm for verification depends on the algorithm used to generate the signature.

Comment: The web host should have nothing to say about it, it's just a collection of PHP files, no different then uploading any set of PHP files.  It's not an extension that needs to be loaded, although it may need some like BCMATH etc. but they are pretty basic ones.  I use PHPSecLib mainly because it's SSH interface is way better the the ssh2 extension that only works on linux.

Comment: @miken32 YAY, got it working! Thanks very much for your help. Looking back at the versions in my repo, it looks like I had the answer at various stages, albeit broken, but the key (pardon the pun) to the problem was the missing line breaks when I was formatting the PEM key. I have been banging my head for 2 days over this, so again thank you very much for the line breaks.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix agreed, the only times I've had to do any encryption or verification in php in the past, I've used phpseclib. This was painful in comparison, though it will of course be easier should I have to do the same again in the future. As for the host, I find their support staff pretty useless, hiding behind the boring boilerplate response that they do not support customer scripts. I wanted to find out their reasoning for not including phpseclib in the system php installation, before adding a local version of the phpseclib modules, though now thankfully I do not have to do so.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix haha, just got my hosts reply `Thank you for your patience. RSA module is currently not supported in PHP and Perl installation on our server. Also, M2Crypto module is not installed in Python. We might update this in near future. However, there is no ETA on this.` which translates to "now we have repeated the problem that you reported, go away", lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @miken32 I have now finally fixed the code. Turns out all I was missing was a couple of line breaks when formatting the PEM key. So the final, and very simple code is:

```
// Get base64 encoded public key.
// NOTE: this is just for testing the code, final production code stores the public key in a db.
$pubkey = $_POST['pubkey'];

// Convert pubkey in to PEM format (don't forget the line breaks).
$pubkey_pem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n$pubkey\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

// Get public key.
$key = openssl_pkey_get_public($pubkey_pem);

if ($key == 0)
{
    $result = "Bad key zero.";
}
elseif ($key == false)
{
    $result = "Bad key false.";
}
else
{
    // Verify signature (use the same algorithm used to sign the msg).
    $result = openssl_verify($msg, base64_decode($signature), $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

    if ($result == 1)
    {
        $result = "Verified";
    }
    elseif ($result == 0)
    {
        $result = "Unverified";
    }
    else
    {
        $result = "Unknown verification response";
    }

}

// do something with the result.
```

Comment: `base64_decode` need to be  `base64_decode(strtr($signature, '-_', '+/'))` if this is a JWT token. look at [This answer about related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41232059/1041046)